# Start-Job { } | Receive-Job -Wait -Force returns only partial results of batched Get-AzStorageBlob with MaxCount and ContinuationToken

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, start-job

When we call the following, it returns thousands of results.

```
$storageContainer = 
  New-AzStorageContext -ConnectionString $StorageAccountConnectionString `
    | Get-AzStorageContainer -Name $BlobContainerName;

$MaxCount = 100;
$Token = $Null;

do
{
    $Blobs = $storageContainer | Get-AzStorageBlob `
      -MaxCount $MaxCount `
      -ContinuationToken $Token;

    if($Blobs.Length -le 0) { Break; }

    $Token = $Blobs[$blobs.Count -1].ContinuationToken;

    # leave the blobs on the pipeline.
    $Blobs;
}
While ($Null -ne $Token);
```

When we wrap it in `Start-Job { } | Receive-Job -Wait -Force`, it returns only 257 results.

```
# Use `Start-Job` to avoid dependency conflicts. 
# See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/resolving-powershell-module-assembly-dependency-conflicts/#solving-the-issue-in-powershell-itself
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {

    $storageContainer = 
      New-AzStorageContext -ConnectionString $using:StorageAccountConnectionString `
        | Get-AzStorageContainer -Name $using:BlobContainerName;

    $MaxCount = 100;
    $Token = $Null;

    do
     {
         $Blobs = $storageContainer | Get-AzStorageBlob `
            -MaxCount $MaxCount `
            -ContinuationToken $Token;

         if($Blobs.Length -le 0) { Break; }

         $Token = $Blobs[$blobs.Count -1].ContinuationToken;

         $Blobs;
     }
     While ($Token -ne $Null)

} | Receive-Job -Wait -Force;
```

How can we make `Start-Job { } | Receive-Job -Wait -Force` return *all* the results?